# Is there any way to add new user to recommender system without rebuilding the model in ml.net recommender task?

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I have recommender system based on some dataset. But what if i want to add new user to and predict for this user recommendation? Question based on this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/movie-recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to predict, then no, you simply call CreatePredictionEngine passing in your user data

If you want to update your model with data for the new user, then you have to rebuild the model.

Comment: Is there simple way to rebuild the model (I mean retrain, not training from scratch)?

Comment: Not in my experience, the full model gets built whenever you add new data. However I am not familiar with ML.Net, tbh. Is there a concern around how long retraining takes? If not, you can simply automate.